# AfxMessageBox appears behind MFC dialog

Tags: c++, mfc, modal-dialog

In the main view of my application, I create a modeless dialog i.e.:

```
CMyDialog dlg;
int returnval = dlg.doModal();
```

Now this is the first time this happens to me, but in this particular dialog, if I want to display a message box on a button press, it **always** appears behind the dialog. If I press the alt key on the keyboard, then it gains focus and comes up front.

```
int nResult = AfxMessageBox(_T("Are you sure you want to delete this file?"), MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION|MB_SETFOREGROUND | MB_TOPMOST | MB_TASKMODAL);
if(nResult == IDNO){
    return;
}
else{
...
}
```

I am wondering what have I done or what option I checked that would result in this behaviour ?

---

EDIT: Here is the small portion of code in my OnInitDialog function, I commented out all the rest and the same behaviour remains:

```
CDialog::OnInitDialog();
DEVMODE sDevMode;
ZeroMemory(&sDevMode, sizeof(DEVMODE));
sDevMode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);

EnumDisplaySettings(NULL,ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS,&sDevMode);
_screenw = (int)sDevMode.dmPelsWidth;
_screenh = (int)sDevMode.dmPelsHeight;

_dlgx = (int) 50;
_dlgy = (int) 50;
_dlgw = (int) _screenw-100;
_dlgh = (int) _screenh-100;

this->MoveWindow(_dlgx,_dlgy,_dlgw,_dlgh);
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `MessageBox()` function of your `CMyDialog` class?  `AfxMessageBox()` and `CWnd::MessageBox()` differ in the `HWND` parameter that is provided to the underlying `MessageBox()` `Win32` API function.

Comment: Odd, do you set any extended window styles in your dialog initialization function(s)?  Playing with Z-Order perhaps?

Comment: See my edit, I have almost nothing in there.

Comment: Can you show the function where your `MessageBox()` is being displayed?

Comment: I added a button to the dialog, then I clicked add event handler and the only code used in that function is the one I posted. As I said in the other response, I'll just do a new dialog, make sure the message box appears nicely and copy paste the other stuff I had put in there. It's not that much work. It just puzzled me why it was happening..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AfxMessageBox` would always be modal on the top window in Z-order. I don't see any need to pass additional flags to bring it forward. Yes, if the application (main window) is not in focus, you may activate it explicitly before calling `AfxMessageBox`.

The only situation I see message-box not coming forward is when parent window is created by other thread, and `AfxMessageBox` is being called from another thread.

Comment: The dialog is created in the main application thread and the message box is directly called in the dialog on a button press. I just started a new dialog and the message box appears fine. I think this one might be corrupted in some way or the other...

Comment: I tried with setting focus on main window. Don't know what magic it did to you. It did nothing. How this answer was accepted?? Can you explain how it worked on your end.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to workaround this same issue by calling CWnd::PostMessage(0x118) before DoModal(), as reported [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/788540/mfc-cdialog-domodal-cant-show-window-if-parent-window-message-queue-is-busy).

It seems a glitch in MFC architecture, as the dialog is not shown if the underlying message loop is not empty and the only way is to issue a 0x118 message or an ALT keypress (WM_SYSKEYDOWN).

So the workaround for this question could be:

```
CMyDialog dlg;
CWnd::PostMessage(0x118);
int returnval = dlg.doModal();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use MB_APPLMODAL to get it in front of all windows in your application.

What you should do is create the message box as a child of your dialog. Use CWnd::MessageBox for this.

Comment: Tried the MB_APPLMODAL, didn't work. Will try the MessageBox() function instead.

Comment: CWnd::MessageBox also appears behind my dialog until I press the alt key on my keyboard... I guess I'll just delete my dialog and redo a new one... :/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint. Here's another form that work for me if you are not calling DoModal from the main window :

```
void MyApp::OnAppAbout()
{

    CAboutDlg aboutDlg;
    CWnd * pParent = GetMainWnd();
    if (pParent)
        pParent->PostMessage(WM_SYSKEYDOWN);

    aboutDlg.DoModal();
}
```